# How can I restore a website to the "Top Sites" in Firefox after accidentally removing it?

Tags: firefox

The Firefox New Tab page has a feature called "Top Sites" which shows the sites you visit most frequently for easy access. You can manually remove specific websites from this section, but if you do so by mistake, there is no obvious way to undo this operation. How can I restore a site to its former place after I have unintentionally removed it? (Edit: Ideally, I would want to exactly undo the removal and thus restore it to its previous behavior of automatically sorting by frequency of visit.)

(I am currently using Firefox 61.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The websites blocked from the "Top Sites" are stored in the setting `browser.newtabpage.blocked` that can be found in `about:config`. However, the names of the sites are not stored in a human-readable format, so restoring a single website is difficult. The best possibility that I have found is to completely reset the setting, which restores all pages that were dismissed from the Top Sites.

Comment: This sounds like what I was looking for! I'll test it out on the machine in question when I get the chance.

Answer (score 6):

#### How can I restore a site to its former place after I have unintentionally removed it?

First add it back:

> **Add a Top Site**
>
> 1. Hover the mouse pointer anywhere within the Top Sites section of tiles and click on the three-dot menu that appears in the upper right
>      corner.
> 2. Click Add Top Site.
>
>    [image]
> 3. Type in a title and URL for the site, then click Add.
>
>    A tile with the first letter from the title will appear in your Top
>      Sites.

Then put it back in the correct place:

> **Rearrange Top Sites**
>
> Click and hold on a tile and drag it to another spot.
>
> [image]

Source [Customize the New Tab page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-new-tab-page#w_add-a-top-site)

Comment: Will this cause the site to return to its previous behavior of sorting automatically by frequency of recent visits, or will it only pin the site to a specific slot?

Comment: No idea. I don't think it's pinning it. That's is a different command (see the link in the answer).

Comment: It seems this does indeed pin the site, and unpinning it causes it to disappear once again. This isn't ideal, but I'll use it if no one has a better solution that restores the original pre-deletion behavior.

Comment: David's answer is great (as usual), but yes, it *does* actually pin the site to your `New Tab` page.  Honestly, it really is the only solution unless you are willing to manually backup your bookmarks and start over with a new Firefox profile.  While that would get the job done, it is probably just a bit of overkill for one missing tile on the `New Tab` page.

Comment: Perhaps there's a flag I could manually edit in places.sqlite or something?